# SSH Port Forwarding to SQL Server Not Working

Tags: ssh, sql-server, port-forwarding

I am working with an AWS environment containing

- a Ubuntu server to which I can establish an SSH connection
- a MySQL server
- an MS SQL server

I can SSH into the Ubuntu server and from there verify connectivity to the MySQL server on port 3306, and the MSSQL server on port 1433 via telnet.

However, if I specify local port forwarding like this in my SSH connection:

```
  -L 1439:MsSqlIp4Addr:1433 -L 3310:MySqlIp4Addr:3306
```

From my local machine/client I can verify the connection to the MySQL server via `telnet 127.0.0.1 3310`.  But when I attempt to connect to the MSSQL server via `telnet 127.0.0.1 1439`, it just hangs for ~100 seconds and then returns "Connection closed by foreign host".

I've tried swapping the local ports to make sure there was no conflict, and I can consistently connect to the MySQL server but not the MSSQL server.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you _“test”_ with telnet? Do you expect a "Connected to..." message or are you waiting for the server's banner (only applies to some protocols)?

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, even though telnet doesn't work, I can still connect to the SQL Server by specifying `127.0.0.1,1439` using standard SQL Server tools.

Don't know why telnet hangs when testing locally but not on the remote machine.  I guess that just means it's not a valid test of connectivity.